# Exception from container-launch exitCode=1 hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have installed hadoop 2.8.1 in windows without cygwin. I am able to start hadoop by start-all.cmd. But when I run wordcount.jar, I get below error

command : hadoop jar WordCount.jar WordCount G:/Hadoop/input output

```
Application application_1511001920752_0003 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1511001920752_0003_000002 exited with exitCode: 1
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1511001920752_0003_02_000001
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1:
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:972)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:869)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:1170)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:236)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:305)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:84)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Shell output: 1 file(s) moved.
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://DESKTOP-ETS7CRG:8088/cluster/app/application_1511001920752_0003 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
. Failing the application.
```

stderr file in userlogs only contains 1 line : The system cannot find the path specified.
I dont understand which file it is not able to find.

Comment: Can you please also add the command that you are running?

Comment: You need to get the attempt logs

Comment: @cricket_007 How to get this logs?

Comment: Read the output there... `For more detailed output, check the application tracking page`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving a local file as the input file. Wordcount program expects a HDFS file/directory as an input hence it is failing.

Please put the file in HDFS and try once again. It should work.